# Android Make ProgessDialog Uncloseable

Tags: android, progressdialog

How can I make my [ProgessDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) uncloseable, so that the user cannot hit the back key, or touch the screen outside of the dialog to dismiss it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`dialog.setCancelable(false);`

Comment: Thanks! I feel like an idiot for missing that. I kept looking for "closeable" that i missed "cancelable". I will set your answer as best in 10 minutes, when it allows me.

Comment: No problem. I only knew because I had a heck of a time trying to get a progressdialog to come up and do what I wanted recently.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use setCancelable to false

```
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```